# Error compiling ar_bounding_box

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to compile ar_bounding_box in order to use roboearth I get the following error:

... roboearth/latest/object_scanning/ar_bounding_box src/ar_kinect_extractobject.cpp:43:34: fatal error: pcl/common/transform.h: No such file or directory

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43594/error-compiling-ar_bounding_box/) by [DontPanic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3144/dontpanic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-11**:
Do you have pcl installed?

**Comment by [DontPanic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3144/dontpanic/) on 2012-09-11**:
Definitely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please always provide information such as the ros version you are using and have a look at the [support guidelines](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29).

Assuming that you are using Fuerte, I guess that the package you are trying to compile hasn't been updated yet. I cannot find a file transform.h in pcl so I think that it has been renamed. Try editing the file ar_kinect_extraobject.cpp and change the include line to include transforms.h.  Since the package doesn't seem to be ported yet, I would expect further problems, not just this include line.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0